# Client Sided application in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am working on asp.Net, and i am required to build a costing calculator having number of fields and comboboxes with a lot of complex formulas, and there would be almost 50 text fields, each have relation to previous fields or like that, in desktop application its quite easy to build it, but in asp, is there anyway to code in asp.net or some asp.net component with which we can do so, i dont wana use javascript, i want to implement it in code behind c#. There is a way to implement it using Ajax, but that sheet will not work if network or internet is closed, as  server based app does not work if network is off, Let me know what to do.
Atif

Comment: What's wrong with using JavaScript?  And if you want to implement it in C# and not require it to have an active internet connection to work you'll probably need something like Silverlight.

Comment: When i work in Javascript, i dont get any IntelliSense, quite difficult to work without that, and i am doubt for new browser's version, in case of any support for js functions.

Comment: JavaScript in Visual Studio 2010 has improved a lot over earlier versions.  I think you'll have to choose between doing it client side and using C# though.  Well, that or going something like Silverlight.

Comment: dont be aggressive lol, i am stuck in problem, i accepted your comment, it means javascript is the only way to do so?

Comment: You are working with Active **Server** Pages and you want you application to work when there is no server??? You'll have to have some client-side code then and JavaScript is the usual choice although as @R0MANARMY points out Silverlight would also be an option. Try and break your dependency on Intellisense, reading the APIs is always possible and will make you a better developer in the long run. Choose the right tool for the job not the easiest one.

Comment: I have another requirement, that application should also be able to run on iphone or ipad, like silverlight or flex does not work on that i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [this old MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301832.aspx) that talks about enhancing client side experience using DLLs downloaded from the server.  That might be a marginally useful option to pursue.

Another option is to use something like [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) and write your code in C# and have a compiler translate it to JavaScript.  As I understand it you'll be writing code that's mostly calculations and possibly some validation, that kind of stuff should translate from one language to another more easily.

Last but not least is basically writing a thick client app that will launch from inside a browser.  Your main option for that is [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/).  It will provide for a rich user experience client side and still allow access to the application from a webpage.  It can also be made to work in partially connected situations (such as network being down for whatever reason).

Comment: probably not worth the time for the seemingly hopeless op, but a decent answer for posterity.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez: Thanks, although you're too young to lose faith in people this quickly =).

Comment: and i thought cynicism was a universal trait in developers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please code in c# and use Ajax (update panel). Don't bother about network off or on. You can deploy on server and it work with internet.

Comment: If you're going to do new development UpdatePanel is probably the worst design decision you can make.

Comment: Right right, ok i will make in Javascript, let me know one thing, if we are building ajax based application, then can we use update panel or it is still worst for ajax apps too?

Comment: @Muhammad Atif Agha: My personal opinion is that it's just plain evil.  It's really easy to get started with, but it can actually be slower than a full postback in some cases (which kind of defeats the point of ajax in my eyes).

Comment: You can use PageMethods or AjaxMethods for calling code behind functions from Javascript.